# Organizar string com base em números

Tags: python

Estou aprendendo a programar em Python e para isso faço desafios que encontro na internet de forma a fixar melhor cada método, função etc
Esse desafio consiste em criar uma função que ordene uma string em que cada palavra tem um número de 1-9 no meio de acordo com o número contido sem retira-lo da string.

```
Ex: "Ess1a 4vida 3a 2é re5al" após a função "Ess1a 2é 3a 4vida re5al"
```

O código é o seguinte:

```
    def order(sentence):
        new_sent = []
        for word in sentence.split():
            char = list(word)
                for c in char:
                    if c in str(range(1, 10)):
                        new_sent.insert(int(c)-1, word)  
        return " ".join(new_sent)
```

Ao testar o código ele funcionou para "`is2 Thi1s T4est 3a"` mas não funcionou `para 'Fo1r the2 4of g3ood pe6ople th5e'` .

Não consigo encontrar o problema no código.

Answer (score 1):

O problema do seu código é basicamente o fato de você inserir valores na lista em posições que ainda não existem

```
>>> my_list = []
>>> my_list.insert(5, 'foo')
>>> my_list.insert(4, 'bar')
>>> my_list
['foo', 'bar']
```

Seu primeiro teste funcionou pela ordem como o texto foi inserido

```
>>> my_list = []
>>> my_list.insert(1, 'is2')
>>> my_list.insert(0, 'Thi1s')
>>> my_list.insert(3, 'T4est')
>>> my_list.insert(2, '3a')
>>> my_list
['Thi1s', 'is2', '3a', 'T4est']
```

Qualquer ordem diferente poderia dar um resultado não esperado.
Existe uma forma mais simples de se fazer isso, basta usar a função builtin [sorted](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted):

```
def order_key(word):
    for char in word:
        if char.isdigit():
            return char


print(sorted('Ess1a 4vida 3a 2é re5al'.split(), key=order_key))
```

O parâmetro `key` da função `sorted` determina qual será o critério de organização da lista, no caso criei uma função que retorna o número dentro da palavra.

Outro detalhe, tome cuidado com esse trecho `str(range(1, 10)` em python2 o resultado seria:

```
>>> str(range(1, 10))
'[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]'
```

Já em python3

```
>>> str(range(1, 10))
'range(1, 10)'
```

Acredito que não seja isso que você estava procurando, talvez fosse:

```
>>> map(str, range(1, 10))
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
```

A função buitin [map](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) aplica uma determinada função em todos os itens de um iteravel. Só tome cuidado pois no python3 a função map retorna um gerador.

Comment: Obrigado! Estava em dúvida se inserir valores numa posição ainda inexistente era o problema. Mas ainda fica a dúvida: o que fez o código ordenar corretamente o primeiro teste mas não o segundo? Vou aproveitar essa dica do map em outro código que também estava dando problema, provavelmente esse era o problema.

Comment: Editei a resposta adicionado a explicação do pq o primeiro teste funcionou, da uma olhada. Se ajudou, por favor indique a resposta como a escolhida e/ou de um up nela.